# How do I create a toString method for an ArrayList of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am tasked with creating a `toString()` method for each and every object in an `ArrayList`. I have no idea how to go about doing this. This is the class with the `ArrayList`

```
public class DogManager {
    private ArrayList<Dog> dogList;

    public DogManager() {
        this.dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    }

    public void addDog(String nameOfDog) {
        this.dogList.add(new Dog(nameOfDog));
    }

    public String toString() {
        String results = "+";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.dogList.size(); i++) {
            results += " " + this.dogList.get(i);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

I know the `toString()` is wrong, but I can't figure out how to make it return a description for each of the objects in that list.

Comment: for (Dog dog : this.dogList) {
 result += dog.toString()
} 
? Is this, what you're searching for?
I assume that Dog has a toString function which is implemented by you.

Comment: Yes, I already made a toString method in the Dog class. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close.  The easiest way I can think of is to also implement `toString()` for `Dog`.  Then in your `DogManager` class you can loop through each `Dog` and call its `toString()`.

ie:

```
public String toString() {
    String results = "+";
    for(Dog d : dogList) {
        results += d.toString(); //if you implement toString() for Dog then it will be added here
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

edit: You can also format it however you like.  I notice some answers separate each Dog by ","

Comment: Thanks man! So far I've understood everything I've been taught but it's always ArrayList that I draw a blank on.

Comment: @user3241721 No problem.  For ArrayList, just remember that it contains multiple values.  Your intuition was right that you need to loop through everything.  You just needed to implement `toString` one further time.  If this helped then you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this, no need to loop through the list of dogs (a `List.toString` already does that for you).

```
public class Dog {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog{" + name + "}";
    }
}


public class DogManager {
    private List<Dog> dogs;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DogManager{dogs=" + dogs + "}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString(){
    String toReturn = "[";

    for(Dog currentDog: dogList){
        toReturn+=currentDog.toString()+",";
    } 
    toReturn = toReturn.substring(0,toReturn.length()-1);

    return toReturn+"]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An arraylist is a dynamic array filled with Objects. Why don't you overwrite the toString method in the Dog class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString() {
    String results = "";
    for(Dog d : dogList) {
        results += "," + d.toString();
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `.toString()` method in your `Dog` class and make it override the default `.toString()` method of `Object` class.

```
public class Dog {

String name;
String age;
String race;

@Override
public String toString() {

    return String.format("Name: %s, Age: %s, Race: %s", name, age, race);
}
}
```

Then you can simply call `System.out.println(dog)` for each element of the array and your custom text defined in dog's `.toString()` method will be displayed.